# creating an event of dynamically created an element in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have table element

```
<table class="ActionMenu" id="tblActionMenu" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" >
```

John

```
 $('.ActionMenu tr').click(function (e) {
                alert("abcd");
     });
```

this works great.

now using javascript i have added table that has same class = "ActionMenu" but on click of tr it doesn't work.

how can i get the Message on Click event dynamically created table

Comment: How did you create the table? Can you show us some source?

Answer (score 3):

Probably, when you defined your function the newer table does not exist yet. So assuming you're using latest jQuery Version (1.7.x) use event delegation and capture the event on a common parent (e.g. the `body` element)

```
 $('body').on("click", ".ActionMenu tr", function (e) {
      alert("abcd");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use "live" function... even better if you use "delegate" function.

It works like this:

```
$('.someClass').live('click',function(){}); //adds 'click evt' to every future .someClass inside the DOM

$('#someID').delegate('.someClass','click',function(){}); //adds 'click evt' to every future .someClass inside #someID
```

Search the jQuery api for more information or let me know if you need more help. Good luck!

Comment: `live()` method is deprecated (unless you must use an older jQuery version)

Comment: Thanks for the tip Calderan. I'm still learning jQuery and didn't know live() was deprecated. I would use delegate() anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Check out example on delegated events on http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$('#tblActionMenu').on("click", "tr", function(){
   //do something
});
```